# Firebase: $save to Not Yet Created Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to figure out how to save the result of a `serviceId` to a `services` object on a parent called `provider1`, when the `services` object is yet to be created.

My Firebase data looks like this:

```
"providers" : {
  "provider1" : {
    "name" : "The Whittington Hospital",
  }
}
```

This is how I'm saving the result of the `serviceId`:

```
for (var providerKey in service.providers) {                       
  var providerId = providers.$getRecord(providerKey);             
  providerId.services[serviceId] = true;                          
  providers.$save(providerId);                                     
}
```

But I'm unable to set the `[serviceId]` to `true`, because `services` object doesn't exist yet, it's undefined.

Firebase doesn't allow you to create empty objects, otherwise I would have an empty `services: {}` obj under my `provider1`.

How can I get around such issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's pretty unclear to me how this fails. It doesn't help that your sample data doesn't contain any services. Can you set up a fiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: That's the point. My sample data doesn't contain an empty services object to begin with, Firebase just doesn't allow it. I'll setup a fiddle if that helps...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to just create the object if it doesn't yet exist:

```
for (var providerKey in service.providers) {                       
    var providerId = providers.$getRecord(providerKey);    
    if(!providerId.services){
        providerId.services = {};
    }
    providerId.services[serviceId] = true;                          
    providers.$save(providerId);                                     
}
```

Here's a plunkr demonstrating it: http://plnkr.co/edit/7akqoorVSdpap99RfF1C?p=preview

I realise this is a crude example using their tutorial, so to see it happenning first add a message and then click the button to attach the service to the last message.

Comment: Ahh, that was really helpful. Thanks for the fiddle too!

Comment: Feel free to assign the bounty too if you like the answer :)

Comment: I can't award the bounty until 9 hours from now. Will award it once Stack Overflow allows me.